# Python lamba function to convert to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I am having a list of dictionary representation as follows:

```
a = [{'score': 300, 'id': 3}, {'score': 253, 'id': 2}, {'score': 232, 'id': 1}]
```

I am new to python and I need a python lambda function that could through a output as :

```
dict = [{3:300}, {2:253}, {1:232}]
```

so that i can find the value given key like

```
>>> print dict[3]
>>> 300
```

I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Why do you need a lambda?

Comment: You will be unhappy if you try to turn sets into dict entries.

Comment: @user2357112 well no necessarily lambda..but the main aim is to get the value based on key. Even If there is a way to query 300 by giving id 3 in the set 'a'. That also helps. thats the main motive behind.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams agree. But what do you think on achieving the above motive of this problem. is it doable?

Comment: I don't know why you would need a lambda for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. don't use `dict` as a variable name, because that would shadow the builtin type name `dict`;
2. `{3, 300}` is not a dictionary, `{3:300}` is;

You can use [dict comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
In [6]: dic = {d['id']: d['score'] for d in a}

In [7]: dic
Out[7]: {1: 232, 2: 253, 3: 300}
```

or a dict constructor as @Jon mentioned for backward compatibility since dict-comp is only available on py2.7+ :

```
In [12]: import operator
    ...: dict(map(operator.itemgetter('id', 'score'), a))
Out[12]: {1: 232, 2: 253, 3: 300}
```

Comment: Or, a non dict-comp approach.... `d = dict(map(operator.itemgetter('id', 'score'), a))`

Comment: @JonClements thx for mentioning, edited my answer ;) it just seems a bit uglier IMHO ;P

Comment: @zhangxaochen Yup it's a shame dict-comp's are only 2.7+.. slightly better would be avoiding itemgetter and just using a gen-exp to feed a 2-tuple to dict, or as the OP wanted a lambda, `dict(map(lambda L: L['id'], L['score'], a))` :p

Comment: @JonClements This solution sounds interesting. Please post it as an answer. Would be helpful for others. This also answers to my question on Lambda.